# Selenium Basic HTTP Authentication popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there any way to handle basic http authentication popup?
There are several ancient answers that you can provide authentication using `https://username:password@www.example.com/` url pattern, but as mentioned here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication
this is deprecated and do not work anymore.

Can't handle it with webdriver Alert API (because this is browser alert not js), getting

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no alert open`

Chrome driver revision: 2.29.461571

Answer (score 0):

you can try javascript executor if selenium alert is not working

```
 ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { 
 return
 true; }");
```

see this thread for similar type of problem https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/27

Comment: Not works, cus auth alert is native browser alert, not JavaScript. 
FIY: selenium has alert api to manage alerts without js executor

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this issue can be resolved by doing some settings in IE.
You can follow below steps -

1. Open IE browser
2. Open the site, you want to automate in IE.
3. Enter your credentials to login to your site
4. Once your are logged in, Go to -
           Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Trusted sites
5. Click on Sites
6. Add your site url under websites and close it.
7. Click on Custom level
8. Under User Authentication, select "Automatic logon with current user name and password"
9. Click "OK"
10. Now you can execute your script in any browser like chrome and it will not ask for the credentials for this particular site.

Hope, this will be helpful for you.